# Enable Authorize button in springdoc-openapi-ui for Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring, swagger-ui, openapi, springdoc

How to enable "Authorize" button in [springdoc-openapi-ui](https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos/) (OpenAPI 3.0 `/swagger-ui.html`) for Basic Authentication.

What annotations have to be added to Spring `@Controller` and `@Configuration` classes?

[image: Authorize button]

[image: Authorize form for Basic Authentication]

Comment: [Adding Basic Auth authorization option to OpenAPI/Swagger documentation — Java Spring | by Hamza Sabljakovic | Medium](https://sabljakovich.medium.com/adding-basic-auth-authorization-option-to-openapi-swagger-documentation-java-spring-95abbede27e9)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Define a global security scheme for OpenAPI 3.0 using annotation `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme` in a `@Configuration` bean:

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My API", version = "v1"))
@SecurityScheme(
    name = "basicAuth",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    scheme = "basic"
)
public class OpenApi30Config {

}
```

Annotate `@RestController` with `@SecurityRequirement(name = "basicAuth")`

```
@RestController
@SecurityRequirement(name = "basicAuth")
public class Controller {}
```

OR

Annotate each `@RestController` method requiring Basic Authentication with `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation` referencing the defined security scheme:

```
@Operation(summary = "My endpoint", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "basicAuth"))
```

Comment: How to apply it to all APIs?    
**Edit:** I just got this link https://stackoverflow.com/a/60666209/3249330

Comment: @Evgeniy  I Tried what you have mentioned the UI comes up but no matter what user id password i give it says authorized. any idea?