# Enable Authorize button in springdoc-openapi-ui for Bearer Token Authentication (JWT)

Tags: java, spring, jwt, openapi, springdoc

How to enable "Authorize" button in [springdoc-openapi-ui](https://springdoc.github.io/springdoc-openapi-demos/) (OpenAPI 3.0 `/swagger-ui.html`) for Bearer Token Authentication, for example JWT.

What annotations have to be added to Spring `@Controller` and `@Configuration` classes?

[image: Authorize button]

[image: Authorize form for Bearer Token Authentication]

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Define a global security scheme for OpenAPI 3.0 using annotation `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme` in a `@Configuration` bean:

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My API", version = "v1"))
@SecurityScheme(
    name = "bearerAuth",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    bearerFormat = "JWT",
    scheme = "bearer"
)
public class OpenApi30Config {

}
```

Annotate each `@RestController` method requiring Bearer Token Authentication (JWT) with `@io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.Operation` referencing the defined security scheme:

```
@Operation(summary = "My endpoint", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
```

Comment: I am experimenting with this too. I had thought that after I add a bearer token in the authroization dialog that swagger would automatically add this in the headers for all subsequent requests.. but doesnt seem to

Comment: Is there a way to configure the @SecurityScheme for https requests? Any ideas will be appreciated.

Comment: Guys don't forget that if you are passing the jwt in the header you have to put "in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER" in the SecirityScheme(

Answer (score 85):

I prefer to use bean initialization instead of annotation.

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info; 
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityRequirement; 
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;

@Configuration
public class OpenApi30Config {

  private final String moduleName;
  private final String apiVersion;

  public OpenApi30Config(
      @Value("${module-name}") String moduleName,
      @Value("${api-version}") String apiVersion) {
    this.moduleName = moduleName;
    this.apiVersion = apiVersion;
  }

  @Bean
  public OpenAPI customOpenAPI() {
    final String securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
    final String apiTitle = String.format("%s API", StringUtils.capitalize(moduleName));
    return new OpenAPI()
        .addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
        .components(
            new Components()
                .addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName,
                    new SecurityScheme()
                        .name(securitySchemeName)
                        .type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP)
                        .scheme("bearer")
                        .bearerFormat("JWT")
                )
        )
        .info(new Info().title(apiTitle).version(apiVersion));
  }
}
```

The line of code

```
.addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName))
```

allows to add global security schema and to get rid of writing security to each @Operation
of method.

Comment: This works, but didn't get it to work with annotations. The Authorize Button wouldn't show when I used annotations, but I probably missed sth. there.

Comment: Nice solution to avoid security to each `@Operation` of method.

Comment: import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.Components;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
----
add import command, because there are few ambiguous options

Comment: If you make global security schema, how do you tell swagger that a particular endpoint is opne and should not be marked as privete?

Comment: @JenkaBY why did you use the "@Value" annotation inside the constructor? Instead to avoid 5 lines more, putting in the attributes properly?

Comment: @rios0rios0 You're right. There is no reason to annotate constructor parameters with "@Value". Feel free to change and improve the code.

Comment: @JenkaBY I'm sorry, but I can't. The StackOverflow is giving me the error message: "The edit queue is full at the moment - try again in a few minutes!". I tried for one hour. Can you edit, please?

Comment: Do all operations use defined bean config by default? Because even if I don't use @SecurityRequirement(name = "some name") the defined authorization is still added in my API operations. So this bugs me. Do I need to add those or not? If I have one authorization type. I suppose it makes sense when you have multiple ways of authorization, would that make generated API operations different?

Answer (score 35):

If you want to avoid annotating each and every `@Operation` inside your `@RestController`  with the `security` attribute, you can add this at class level affecting every operation of your controller.

**Please don't forget** that your configuration bean needs to be the same as in the other example:

```
@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(info = @Info(title = "My API", version = "v1"))
@SecurityScheme(
    name = "bearerAuth",
    type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
    bearerFormat = "JWT",
    scheme = "bearer"
)
public class OpenApi30Config {
}
```

### Adding security requirement at class level

All you have to do is just use `@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")` on those classes, where you would like to restrict the API calls. Note, that these annotations are **inherited**, so you can add them to any interface as well.

Create a marker interface with the required annotation:

```
@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
public interface SecuredRestController {
}
```

Add the marker interface to those controllers where you would like to apply the restriction to all operations, for example:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController implements SecuredController {

    @GetMapping
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public String helloWithName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

}
```

You can do this without the marker interface just saying:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
@SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
public class HelloController {
...
}
```

Now you have both operations protected and requiring a JWT token.
[image]

### Adding security requirement at method level

As it was said in another post, you have to add the `@SecurityRequirement` to your `@Operation` annotation of your method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/hello")
public class HelloController {

    @GetMapping
    @Operation(summary = "My endpoint", security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth"))
    public String hello() {
        return "Hello World";
    }

    @GetMapping("/{name}")
    public String helloWithName(@PathVariable String name) {
        return "Hello " + name;
    }

}
```

This restricts only the first operation, but not the second.
[image]

Comment: Thanks, you helped me! However, I'd have appreciated if you put your text "Please don't forget that..." rather at the *beginning* of your answer, it would have saved me one hour of debugging :) I was not interested in "Adding security requirement at method level" so I stopped reading your answer there :)

Answer (score 2):

I have found a cleaner solution.
It works fine for me.

Thanks to @JenkaBY.

```java
package com.xxx.xxx.configuration;

import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.OpenAPI;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.models.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springdoc.core.customizers.OpenApiCustomiser;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AuthOpenApiCustomizer implements OpenApiCustomiser {
    @Override
    public void customise(OpenAPI openApi) {
        var securitySchemeName = "bearerAuth";
        openApi.getComponents().addSecuritySchemes(securitySchemeName, new SecurityScheme().type(SecurityScheme.Type.HTTP).scheme("bearer").bearerFormat("JWT"));
        openApi.addSecurityItem(new SecurityRequirement().addList(securitySchemeName));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @eugene-khyst answer, we can also define global security requirement for all controllers:

```
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.OpenAPIDefinition;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeIn;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.enums.SecuritySchemeType;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.info.Info;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityRequirement;
import io.swagger.v3.oas.annotations.security.SecurityScheme;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@OpenAPIDefinition(
        info = @Info(title = "Channel API", version = "v1"),
        security = @SecurityRequirement(name = "bearerAuth")
)
@SecurityScheme(
        name = "bearerAuth",
        type = SecuritySchemeType.HTTP,
        bearerFormat = "JWT",
        scheme = "bearer",
        in = SecuritySchemeIn.HEADER
)
public class OpenApiConfig {
}
```